# Ubuntu postfix help

Tags: server, email, postfix

I now have this setup in postfix:

```
sudo nano main.cf
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_use_tls = yes

Sudo nano sasl_password
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    user:password
```

And if I run the command:

```
echo "Test mail thingy" | mail -s "Test Postfix Subject" R*******@gmail.com
```

Does it work :)

How do i force postfix to send message to root local to my mail ?

Comment: First of all I am a Linux noob but I want a system that sends me an email in case there are problems on the server such as if it unmount a drive a service goes down or else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: username@gmail.com
```

If there's an existing alias for root, place a `#` in front of it to comment it out. If you want it sent to multiple users, you can specify multiple addresses like this:

```
root: username@gmail.com, anotheruser@gmail.com
```

After editing `/etc/aliases`, apply it with `sudo newaliases`.

Addendum: It did not work, as per comments, because postfix was not configured to accept mail bound for `rene-desktop`, which was the local host name.

This was fixed by adding

```
 mydestionation = rene-desktop
```

near the top of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Comment: Thank you 

When i run this to test : mail -s "Test Email for Root $(date)" root <<< "This is a test email."

Comment: Your message was not delivered to the root@rene-desktop because the domain  rened-esktop was not found. Check if there are spelling errors or excess spaces and try again. - I think its because I made a mistake at the beginning of the postfix installation how do I correct this :)?

Comment: What's the local hostname, and what's `/etc/mailname` containing?

Comment: rene-desktop  :) - I dont have that folder "/etc/mailname"

Comment: Does `mail root@localhost` work?

Comment: No this command just freezes on subject when I press enter :/

Comment: ah, it doesn't freeze. Just enter your message, a blank line, and send the e-mail with Ctrl-D. Or use `echo test | mail -s foobar root@localhost`

Comment: It works without me getting the notification:

"Your message was not delivered to the root@rene-desktop because the domain was not found. Check if there are spelling errors or excess spaces and try again."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88807/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-rene-mortensen).

Comment: Are you there vidarlo  ? I still have trouble writing it wrong when sending mail in some situations - Do you think you can help when you have time? Good evening :)

Comment: If you have a new problem I suggest you ask a new question :)